# Adding Header in REST API breaks backward compatibility

Tags: rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a REST interface defined as below

```
public interface UserService {

    @GZIP
    @POST
    Response createUser(@HeaderParam("hostName") String hostName, User user);

}
```

I want to read two more headers - `addToCache` and `useCache` . The obvious solution is to add the headers in the above signature.

While that would work for explicit HTTP calls over rest clients, modifying the interface signature breaks the backward compatibility in functional test codebase which already connect to the above service using REST proxy service.

The only way out I see is to pass the two params inside the `User` object. Is there another way out?

Comment: I was able to satisfy my requirements by implementing a `ContainerRequestFilter` and `ContainerResponseFilter` which did the needful.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject header params as fields in the implementation class:

```
public interface UserService {
    Response createUser(String hostName, User user);
}

@Path("/userservice")
public class UserServiceRestImpl implements UserService{

    @HeaderParam("addToCache")
    private String addToCache;

    @HeaderParam("useCache")
    private String useCache;

    @GZIP
    @POST
    Response createUser(@HeaderParam("hostName") String hostName, User user){
        System.out.println(addToCache);
        System.out.println(useCache);
    }
}
```

UPDATED:
try to disable auto scan and specify the resource explicitly:

```
<!-- disabled auto scanning
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
        -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>com.yourpackage.UserServiceRestImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

UPDATED2: Also you can try to inject @Context HttpHeaders  instead of @HeaderParam:

```
private @Context HttpHeaders headers;

...

String addToCache = headers.getHeaderString("addToCache");
```

Comment: This does not work. I am seeing


    `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap]`
     `java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003385: It is illegal to inject a @HeaderParam into a singleton`

Comment: try to disable auto scan.

Comment: The reason I was facing the error was because that the _impl_ is registered as a singleton in the JAX RS `Application`.